# nvidia driver stops working after kernel update

Tags: nvidia, kernel, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update my nvidia modules after updating my kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173721/how-do-i-update-my-nvidia-modules-after-updating-my-kernel)

At work I have a desktop with an nvidia card.

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 660 Ti] [10de:1183] (rev a1)`

When ever I get an update that requires a reboot (Linux/kernel update). The graphics stops working, and I have to login with text terminal. I then type `sudo jockey-text --disable=xorg:nvidia_current` and `sudo reboot`. This allows me to login in a low res graphics mode. I Then reinstall, and then enable the nvidia driver, then logout/reboot.

Is there a way to fix this so that the nvidia driver is built into the new kernel?

I have DKMS and kernel headers installed.

Comment: So anyone have a reference to the duplicate?

Comment: I have just looked at every question these users ever wrote and there is no mention of any similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

To insure that you receive all Nvidia updates without need to reinstall them each time kernel updates use PPA below

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Steinar, your comment seems a bit random. Is it on the correct question?