# How can I prevent Nouveau driver from reinstalling everytime I do a linux kernel update?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, nouveau

I am using the proprietary NVidia drivers from NVidia's website.  I follow the directions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023036/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-with-secure-boot-enabled) to install it.  However, every time I do a kernel upgrade it reinstalls Nouveau and it's this whole process to revert to my custom drivers.  Is there any way to blacklist the Nouveau driver somehow and prevent it from reverting to reinstalling those drivers?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is not `nouveau` is reinstalled, It is always installed, because it is a part of a kernel. The problem is that you install Nvidia a wrong way and it is not using dkms to rebuild after a kernel upgrade.

Comment: Oh interesting, thank you for the explanation.  Do I need to do something like this? https://askubuntu.com/a/850871/1160635
I checked the support docs for the driver I'm using and it mentions this: "Due to the lack of secure storage for private keys that can be utilized by automated processes such as DKMS, it is not possible to use DKMS in conjunction with the module signing support built into nvidia-installer."  The module signing is exactly why I manually installed the driver to begin with, since the one from the ubuntu repo seemed to have trouble signing with secure boot....

Comment: Why don't just disable Secure Boot? It doesn't give any security but brings lots of inconvenience.